# how to get value from DOMTokenList

Tags: javascript, dom

I have `DOMTokenList` in `console.log()`

```
let tag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let list = tag.classList;
console.log(list);
```

View from Console:

```
DOMTokenList []
0: "Konop_1"
length: 1
value: "Konop_1"
<prototype>: DOMTokenListPrototype { item: item(), contains: contains(), add: add(), … }
```

[image]

How I can get only value?

```
console.log(list.value); //-> empty string
```

​

Comment: See [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList). I strongly recommend always checking MDN before posting, you'll find your answer easily 95% of the time.

Comment: `list.value` will work. Can you give us a [mcve]? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I've been trying to catch it for 6 hours, I've been checking it on MDN without success...

Comment: Code it's from OpenLayers Map app, can't reproduce because it's in Intranet. But in console.log I have  DOMTokenList as in question.

Comment: `list.value` -> `list[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have one value or would like to return the entire value of the class attribute you can use the property `className`:

```js
let tag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
console.log(tag.className);
```

```html
<body class="Konop_1"></body>
```

If there are more values you can use the `classList`. Here is an example on how you look for a specific one value and iterate the list:

```js
let tag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let list = tag.classList;

if(list.contains('Konop_1')){
  console.log('has "Konop_1"');
}

list.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<body class="Konop_1 other"></body>
```

Comment: You don't have to iterate, [`DOMTokenList.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/value) *'...is a stringifier that returns the value of the list serialized as a string...'*

Answer (score 0):

`DOMTokenList` is not traited as an array but you can force javascript to consider it like an `Array` by using the [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
let tag = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
let classes = Array.from(tag.classList);

console.log(classes);
```

```html
<h2 class="test">Title</h2>
<h2 class="test test2">Title</h2>
```

As you will have list of all classes contains in the `tag.classList` property as an Array you can do whatever you want

Comment: `DOMTokenList` does implement methods to provide iterators as well ie. [`DOMTokenList.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/values). As noted in comments above all this is covered in the docs.